# Using ComponentFactoryResolver with Reactive Forms

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm working on a form "wizard" component that sets up a form for a user to complete in sections. The sections themselves are dynamically defined. The wizard generates a reactive form, specifies the `formGroup` and `formGroupName` directives, and then uses `ComponentFactoryResolver` to dynamically generate the component responsible for rendering the inputs for each section of the form.

I've re-created a basic demonstration here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-issue-repro2-pdtlnj

There are two questions here:

The only way I was able to get this to work in the app is by specifying a `viewProvider` *in* the dynamically generated components. This is not ideal as it's extra overhead that will be repeated - is it possible to specify these providers in the host, where the component is generated? I've tried adding `ControlContainer` providers to the `Injector` it creates, but nothing has worked.

The other question is, is it possible to set up `TestBed` so that I can test only the "child" components without completely recreating the host structure with the `FormGroup` and `FormGroupName`? I suspect that if the first question can be resolved, I could do something similar in the tests.

Comment: Ran into the same issue today. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @MisterMonk unfortunately, I did not